# Why does using System.Data.Sqlite raise exception Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, system.data.sqlite, .net-standard-2.1

I am writing a C# program in Visual Studio 2019 (Windows 10, .Net 4.72).   My program uses System.Data.Sqlite.   I just copied all the source files from an earlier Windows 7 machine, got it to compile and run, but then I ended up with this message as soon as I reached a line of code that established an SQLConnection:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in ABC.exe
> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

> The program '[4108] ABC.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I did not use any of the dll's from the previous installation - rather, I used NuGet to download the up-to-date ones.   I also downloaded NETStandard.Library.Ref (which contains NetStandard.dll Version 2.1), but it did not work when I tried to install it.

I would use .net 5 or 6, but my program needs a media player, which doesn't seem to be in .Net Core.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because .NET Framework does not implement .NET Standard 2.1, you cannot consume any .NET Standard 2.1 libraries in .NET Framework projects. Besides, the WPF `MediaPlayer` control is available on .NET Core, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#applies-to, so I wonder why you said differently.

Comment: @LexLi  I will check out what you said about the WPF MediaPlayer.   Thanks for the tip, as I'd prefer to use .NET Core if the WPF MediaPlayer works.  Re: 2.1 - that makes sense, and it makes me think I am using the wrong System.Data.Sqlite.dll version.   Again, thanks for your help.